# Counting number of letters in a SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, swift, count, sklabelnode

I want to count the amount of letters in the text of a sklablenode, is this possible?

So if:

```
mySklabelnode = SKLabelNode()
mySklabelnode.text = "testing"
```

Than I want the result to be: 7

How can this be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`text` is just a `String` so you can cast it to `NSString` and then call `length` on it.

```
SKLabelNode *mySklabelnode = [[SKLabelNode alloc] init];
mySklabelnode.text = @"testing";

NSLog(@"%d",mySklabelnode.text.length);
```

In Swift without casting

```
let mySklabelnode = SKLabelNode()
mySklabelnode.text = "testing"
println("\(count(mySklabelnode.text))")
```

Or in Swift with casting

```
let mySklabelnode = SKLabelNode()
mySklabelnode.text = "testing"

println("\((mySklabelnode.text as NSString).length)")
```

**Note**:  When checking a string count or length with these methods, you need to take extra consideration if emojis might be used in the string, as they are unicode characters of multipart UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Thank you, can you translate it so Swift please?

Comment: Give me one sec to double check this

Comment: What is the difference between printf and println? because printf also doesnt work at my xcode

Comment: @sdd That was a typo on my part.  I've been writing in C too much lately.  Use println.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77423/discussion-between-frankie-and-sdd).

Comment: The `NSString` `length` method returns the number of UTF-16 code units, **not** the number of characters. Most emoji are two UTF-16 code units in length as are surrogate pairs and there are characters that require even more units such as flags. For the unicode string "AB FG"`,mySklabelnode.text.length` returns 11, `count(mySklabelnode.text)` returns 7 and `(mySklabelnode.text as NSString).length` returns 11.

Comment: The OP was not specific about whether they were trying to count UTF-16 code units or characters and so I feel I provided a correct answer according to the OP's question and requirements. "I want the result to be 7".  Feel free to post an additional answer.  I would be happy to learn more about the subject.

Comment: Suggestion: Add a warning that the answer does not apply to unicode characters that are multiple UTF-16 code units such as emoji.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count`.

`count(mySklabelnode.text)`

Comment: I am using Swift and there is no such method. The only thing that is showing up is: mySklabelnode.text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(<#encoding: NSStringEncoding#>)